# PostgreSQL: Create JSON message with specific Objects selected in an Array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, api, object

I have data in this format:

`[{"id":"b","type":"user"},{"id":"c","type":"system"}]`

Would like to generate JSON message with only "id" selected, for example:

`[{"id":"b"},{"id":"c"}]`

So far I was only able to split them and remove "type", then concatenate with []

```
select json_array_elements_text(column1)::jsonb #- '{type}'
from (
    select '[{"id":"b","type":"user"},{"id":"c","type":"system"}]'::json as column1
) t
```

Are there a better way to do it (I'm sure there is), please help thanks.

Edit:

There might be other properties in addition to "id" and "type" added in future, code will need to reference to "id" only.
`[{"id":"b","type":"user"},{"id":"c","type":"system"}, {"id":"d","type":"system", "flag":"Y"}]`

Comment: `jsonb` would improve it somewhat, but the proper solution would be to avoid JSON in the database and to normalize the data model.

Comment: thanks for the reply @LaurenzAlbe, the source data is system generated JSON message in above format, I only need to "id" component and to pass it on to a separate system via API Post. If I could apply only few functions to get the result, then that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I have to advice next flow:

```
select array_agg(row_to_json(t.*)) from (
    select id
    from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id":"b","type":"user"},{"id":"c","type":"system"}]'::jsonb) as x(id varchar, type varchar)
) t;
```

You can [play SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a01ca1cf1be739a000a1d288fe16d25c&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Comment: Thanks @Slava, I wonder if there is way to avoid using "type" key, as potentially there might be additional properties or key-value pairs added to an object in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that doesn't referencing other properties in JSON objects.

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('id', id)) as id
from (
    select json_array_elements('[{"id":"b","type":"user"},{"id":"c","type":"system"}, {"id":"d","type":"system", "flag":"Y"}]'::json)::json->'id' as id
    ) t
```